# PHP / MySQL: query is executed properly, affected_rows returns -1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to delete a row from a table, and check if it worked / if a row has been found and removed. I use the following query to do so:
`DELETE FROM TableName WHERE val1=1 AND val2=2 AND val3=3`. I send that code via the connection `$conn` using a prepare and execute function, and it works just fine. The row I'm looking for is being found and deleted. But if I want to check if it worked using `$conn->affected_rows`it returns -1, which means that an error occured. I don't understand, where the error could be, that `affected_rows`returns -1, even though the query has been executed properly...

If you do not understand the issue, feel free to ask in a comment.

code:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM ComTasks WHERE comid=? AND obj=? AND type=0";
$response = paramQuery($conn, $query, array($communityid, $userid), "ss");
echo $conn->affected_rows; //=> -1

function paramQuery($conn, $query, $params, $str){
    if(!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if($stmt === false) return -1;
    for($i=0; $i<count($params); $i++){
        $params[$i] = &$params[$i];
    }
    array_unshift($params, $str);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: please show the code.

Comment: and did you check for `$conn->error`?

Comment: $conn->error returns nothing

Comment: Just to be certain what is the value of $response after the method is called?

Comment: Your code failed for a few reasons here. You're trying to echo a function before the method kicks in. Then you're using `get_result()` after the execution, which doesn't work with any other function but a result set from a SELECT http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: @Unknown Please edit your question so it does contain the output of `var_dump($response)` and `var_dump($stmt->execute());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a prepared statement and $stmt, the affected_rows should also be called from $stmt:

```
$stmt->affected_rows;
```

However since you wrapped it in a function, and do a $stmt-close(), this will not work outside of the function call. You may have to adjust your function to store that value before close, and before the return of the function.

Some more info here on php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: I'll try this, and it appears to make sense. (I was pretty tired when I asked the question here, and woke up with the same idea :D)